# is it possible to calculate $\int^{1}_{0}x^{2}f(x)dx$ given $\int^{1}_{0}xf(x)dx$ and $\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was given the following values of definite integrals:

$$\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx = 1$$

and

$$\int^{1}_{0}xf(x)dx = 5$$

from these is it possible to calculate the value of

$$\int^{1}_{0}x^{2}f(x)dx$$

I thought this could be solved by integration by parts, but it's trickier than I thought. Because from $\int u' v = uv - \int uv'$ and letting $v = x^{2}$ and $v' = 2x$ doesn't work because the $\int uv' = 2\int xF(x) $ where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. Similarly, setting $v = f(x)$ makes no sense because we don't have any information about $f'(x)$.

Comment: I would say no, if you see $f$ as a probability distribution this would mean that if you know the first two moments then you could get all the others. In fact I beleive that for any $c \in \mathbb R$ you can find $f$ polynomial which solves the first two equations but with the third integral being equal to $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

Consider $$f_1(x)= 54x-26,$$

and $$f_2(x) =\begin{cases}
-9 &  x < \frac{9}{10}\\
91 & x \geq \frac{9}{10}
\end{cases}.$$